Failed to resolve entry for package "ts-retry". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json
I am getting this error while running a react app using vite. I am using a package from private npm registry (@ats/graphql) which has dependency of this package ts-retry.
Any help would be appreciated.
FYI, This works fine with CRA.
X [ERROR] Failed to resolve entry for package "ts-retry". The package may have incorrect main/module/exports specified in its package.json. [plugin vite:dep-pre-bundle]

node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1374:21:
  1374 │         let result = await callback({
       ╵                      ^

at packageEntryFailure (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48302:17)
at resolvePackageEntry (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48299:5)
at tryNodeResolve (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48069:20)
at Context.resolveId (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:47819:28)
at Object.resolveId (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:51096:64)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:68287:21
at async file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48642:34
at async requestCallbacks.on-resolve (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1374:22)
at async handleRequest (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:732:11)

This error came from the "onResolve" callback registered here:
node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1293:20:
  1293 │       let promise = setup({
       ╵                     ^

at setup (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:48622:19)
at handlePlugins (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1293:21)
at buildOrContextImpl (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:979:5)
at Object.buildOrContext (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:788:5)
at C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:68
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Object.context (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2224:27)
at Object.context (C:\Repositories\Practice\ice-configuration-ui-v2\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:2048:58)
at prepareEsbuildOptimizerRun (file:///C:/Repositories/Practice/ice-configuration-ui-v2/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-whKeNLxG.js:52821:35)

The plugin "vite:dep-pre-bundle" was triggered by this import
node_modules/@ats/graphql/dist/helper/queryMutate.js:9:25:
  9 │ var ts_retry_1 = require("ts-retry");
    ╵                          ~~~~~~~~~~

Node.js v18.16.0
Vite: 5.2.0
vite.config.js file:
import { defineConfig } from "vitest/config";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import * as path from "path";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  define: {
    global: {},
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: [
      { find: "@", replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src") },
    ],
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000,
  },
});


I am also facing similar issue with my vite application
